# How to configure FBA authentication in SharePoint 2013 ? User should be stored in sql-server

Tags: 2013, 2010

How to configure FBA Authentication in `SharePoint 2013` ?  User should be stored in `SQL-Server` ?

Answer (score 1):

Configure FBA:

https://chrisbarba.com/2013/07/16/sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-fba/

SQL Server will have FBA DB and it will store User Information like Username, Last Name detail.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 by default Windows Authentication is enabled and selected when creating a new web application, but we can configure Forms-Based Authentication as well for the web applications .

[image]

We need to select the option Enable Forms based Authentication(FBA) while creating new Web Application in SharePoint 2013 . and we can acheive this using SQL Membership Provider.

Here , after implementing this while trying to login to a site under FBA configured web applications you'll be redirected to default logon page where you need to select the logon type from the options provided.

[image]

Please refer https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider/ for more info on FBA configuration in SharePoint 2013